# Use a variable to a variable

Tags: javascript, variables

I want to pass a variable into a variable

This is what I want

```
uk.objects.ARG
```

I have

```
 var d= ARG
```

how can I get uk.objects.ARG?

I tried

```
uk.objects.d
```

, javascript stores it as the string, not a variable

What should I do in order to make it as a variable ?

Comment: Don't confuse *variables* (`d`, `uk`) with *properties* (`objects`, `ARG`) of objects.

Answer (score 4):

You can access JavaScript objects' properties also with the bracket notation:

```
object[property] = value;
```

The same works for reading. So in your case you could do the following:

```
var value = uk.objects[d]
```

Comment: (sidenote) `field` AKA `key` (or *property*) Usually we talk about key-value pairs, not *fields*.

Comment: (sidenote) *array index notation* is misleading, here we're talking about *properties*, not indexes and specially not *index notation*. Perhaps  what you meant to say is `bracket notation`.

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan: Thanks, your are right. I edited my answer to be more clear.

Answer (score 4):

I think what you are looking for is perhaps:

```
var d = "ARG";

uk.objects[d];
```